# How to rapidly update composable using ViewModel in real time

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a ViewModel that keeps a timer:

```
class GameViewModel @Inject constructor(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application), PlayStopWatch.PlayClockListener {


  val playTime = MutableLiveData<Long>()

 override fun onPlayClockTick(elapsedTime: Long) {
        playTime.value = elapsedTime
    }
}
```

I would like to use it to update a clock in this composable but I don't think I'm understanding the documentation properly:

```
@Composable
fun PlayTime(viewModel: GameViewModel) {

val playTime by remember { mutableStateOf(viewModel.gameTime)}
    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.icon_timer),
            contentDescription = "Timer Icon",
            tint = yellow,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(64.dp)
        )
        Text(
            "$playTime",
            color = yellow,
            fontFamily = Montserrat,
            fontWeight = FontWeight(700),
            fontSize = 60.sp,
            letterSpacing = -0.5.sp,
            lineHeight = 72.sp,

            )
    }//: End Row
    Text(
        text = "Tap Screen to Start Play",
        color = white_97,
        style = ff.h5

    )
```

}

The view model is passed down from a view tree that includes this view

```
@Composable
fun StartPlayView(viewModel:GameViewModel) {
    Surface(
        color = background_primary,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(heightWeight(32f)))
            MenuBar()
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(heightWeight(32f)))
            ScoresBar()
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(heightWeight(76f)))
            PauseButton()
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(heightWeight(200f)))
            PlayTime(viewModel)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(heightWeight(200f)))
            BottomBar()
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(heightWeight(16f)))


        }

    }
}
```

Which gets passed the viewModel from a NavGraphBuilder via Android's build in HiltViewModel:

```
@Composable
fun SetupNavGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.StartPlay.route
    ){
        // Login View
        composable(
            route = Screen.Login.route
        ){
   
     
        composable(route = Screen.StartPlay.route){ StartPlayView(hiltViewModel()) }

      

    }
}
```

How do I keep the TextView in the PlayTime view display the current time on the timer in real time?

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this. the `delay()` is in millis, so the `playTime` will only be updated every seconds. just change that based on your needs

```kotlin
fun startPlayTimeCounter() {
    job = coroutineScope.launch {
        val initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        var playTime: Long
    
        while (true) {
            playTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - initialTime
            delay(1000L)
        }
    }
}
```

and stop the timer by cancelling the job

```kotlin
fun stopPlayTimeCounter() {
    job?.cancel()
}
```

Comment: My issue is less about updating the time in the viewModel and more about updating the view with the new time.

Comment: I see, because you already use `LiveData` to store the `playTime`. You could do something like `val playTime = gameViewModel.playTime.observeAsState()` in Composable.